# Anjuta IDE - Simple Python Question

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'm new to Linux, Python and the Anjuta IDE.

I have created a new file called hello.py. This is the contents of that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello World!"
```

All I want to do is run this in the terminal. I go to **Run** > **Execute** but I get the following error message:

> Program 'home/joe/Programming/Python//hello.py' does not have execution permission

How do I get this really simple program to run?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open a shell, cd to the folder where the file is located and execute `chmod +x hello.py`.

Comment: Then you'll need to type `hello.py` to actually run the program.

Comment: @GreenMatt: `./hello.py` unless it's in your PATH

Comment: Thanks for this. On a side note: I wonder why Anjuta doesn't make this happen automatically (since there is a "Run" option for each file it would make sense to automate this).

Answer (score 2):

ZeissS' solution will work and is generally preferred to this, but for the sake of completeness, you could also open a shell, cd to the appropriate directory, and type:

> python hello.py

Comment: I think he wants to run it from his IDE, which, as I understand from the error, executes the file directly.

Comment: @ZeissS:  You may be correct, although "All I want to do is run this in the terminal." says to me he wants to run it from a shell prompt.  If the attempt is from the IDE, I'd hope it would either be smart enough to run a Python program or configurable enough for  an appropriate change to be made.  Otherwise, a terminal window may be necessary.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I'm used to Xcode and I just wanted to be able to test the file in Anjuta's terminal.